# Before visiting Facebook two cookies got created(fr and sb)

Tags: cookies, facebook, user-tracking

I have cleared all the cookies on my Chrome browser, closed the browser and opened Chrome, navigated to `chrome://settings/siteData`

I see two new Facebook fr and sb cookies created right away, before visiting Facebook. How did these two cookies get created?

Comment: "How are they created?" Doesn't appear to be the relevant question. Were they deleted? Do you have browser extensions?

Comment: Those cookie probably get created due to request to Facebook trackers

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `chrome://settings/content/notifications`. If notifications from Facebook are allowed (you find `https://www.facebook.com:443` on the Allow list), your browser will connect Facebook in the background to get new notifications. This feature may add some cookies even before you have (wittingly) accessed any pages.